# How to import other applications exported files in .test.js files in single-spa environment

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, single-spa

Hi I actually need to import exported files from one application(commons) to other application(login) in some jest files, but it is not getting detected by jest.

Jest Test file:

```
import { auth as ServiceAuth } from "@dfs/standard"
import { ContextAlert } from '@dfs/standard';

describe("login page", () => {
    it("test case 1", () => {
        const ContextAlert = useContext(ContextAlert );
        expect(ContextAlert).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

Error Message:

FAIL  src/Components/LoginPage.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module '@dfs/standard' from 'LoginPage.test.js'

> 1 | import { auth as ServiceAuth } from "@dfs/standard"
    | ^
  2 | import { ContextAlert } from '@dfs/standard';
  3 | 
  4 | describe("login page", () => {

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:299:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/LoginPage.test.js:1:1)
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest"
},
moduleNameMapper: {
  "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity- 
obj-proxy",
   }
};
```

But the file is getting imported in the component files with the same syntax.
How can I import the file in the jest test file ?

Answer (score 1):

Jest is a very different environment than the browser, and resolving modules is also different. The code being loaded in Jest is not bundled and has not been processed through Webpack so externals are not resolved at run-time.

To enable unit tests with [cross microfrontend imports](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#cross-microfrontend-imports), these are your options:

- Publish mocks for that shared dependency (so that the mock and the actual implementation are nearest to each other)
- Mock the shared dependency with Jest’s `moduleNameMapper` configuration
- Mock the shared dependency locally in a `__mocks__` file
- Publish the shared dependency to a registry (npm or some other internal registry such as artifactory) and install it as a devDependency locally so that Jest can resolve it locally (though this will likely require a separate build to execute in jest/node environment)

The option you choose depends on your organization's needs.

See also: https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa.js.org/issues/389